# How to move var value from one function to the other? Javascript

Tags: javascript

I don't know how to get skoras value from one function to the other. Both of the functions are onClick ones and activate with a press of the button.

```js
var skoras = 10;
function rollDice() {
  // Local Variables            
  var die1 = document.getElementById("die1");
  var die2 = document.getElementById("die2");
  var status = document.getElementById("status");
  var score = document.getElementById("score");
  var nextRoom = document.getElementById("nextRoom");
  var ok = document.getElementsByClassName("ok");
  //score              
  for (i = 1; i > 0; i--) {
    skoras -= 1;
    skoras += diceTotal;
  }
}
function checkValue() {
  skoras--;
}
```

Comment: Where do get the value for `diceTotal` .. your function should be working properly although it can be optimized.

Comment: Your variable is on the global scope, so it should be accessible from both functions

Comment: I made you a snippet. You can add relevant HMTL to make a [mcve]

Comment: Also this runs ONCE so why the loop? `for (i = 1; i > 0; i--) {
    skoras -= 1;
    skoras += diceTotal;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

You defined `skoras` on top on the function, so they can access it directly

Example

```js
var skoras = 10;

function add(value) {
    skoras += value;
}

function display() {
    console.log("skoras =", skoras);
}

display();
add(2);
display();
```

Comment: This really doesn't help OP understand why their function is not working.